# Handling abbreviated numbers + pluralization w/ react-intl

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, react-intl

I'd like to be able to display strings like "1,000 cars" as "1K cars" (if appropriate for the locale). Is there a way to handle this using [react-intl](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl)?

I'm still trying to wrap my head around the API and I'm not sure if this is something that a custom formatter is intended to handle, and if so, I'm not clear on how to set that up.

Thanks!